# How to reconcile the explanations for why sound travel faster in solid than air?

Tags: waves, acoustics, education

In high school (and almost all the youtube videos), we are often taught that sound travels faster in solid than air because solids are generally denser; this allows the air particles to more readily collide with each other, thereby transmitting the energy more quickly.

The formula for speed of sound is clearly flying in the face of this explanation! The formula is given by
$$
v=\sqrt{\frac{B}\rho}
$$
where $B$ is the bulk modulus and $\rho$ is the density. From this formula, it is clear that speed of sound decreases as density increases.

I don't really need an explanation as to why this formula is correct; instead, I hope to know if there is any way to reconcile these two seemingly contradictory explanations. If not, can I get some sort of confirmation that any reasoning that appeals to density as a reason for higher speed of sound is flat out wrong?

Comment: "In high school (and almost all the youtube videos), we are often taught..." No *we* aren't.

Comment: Did you consider that the numerator in the square root might also increase?

Comment: Well, lucky for you to have teachers who taught accurate physics. But like what I said, I understand how that formula still suggests that speed of sound is faster in solid than air. My question is directed towards whether the former explanation is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does sound travel faster in iron than mercury even though mercury has a higher density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101895/why-does-sound-travel-faster-in-iron-than-mercury-even-though-mercury-has-a-high)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/555773/195949

Answer (score 4):

The bulk modulus (roughly the resistance to compression) of STP air is around $10^5\,{\rm Pa}$, while the bulk modulus of steel $1.6\times 10^{11}\,{\rm Pa}$. That's a factor of 1,600,000 in the numerator (before the square root).

Meanwhile, steel is around 7,000 times the density of air, leading to a speed-of-sound in steel around Mach 15-ish. (The listed value is 14.978).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So would you say that what's often being taught (i.e. speed of sound in solid is faster because it is denser) is categorically wrong?

Comment: @Tham: ....yes.